# Do I need to use session_start() in PHP to use $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session-variables

I heard my friend say that I don't have to use `session_start()` to use `$_SESSION` in PHP? Is that true? If yes, how do I make it work? If I remove `session_start()` from my code, I can no longer get `$_SESSION` to work.

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php - Plus, show us that link to that "news" that you read. *"If I remove `session_start()` from my code, I can no longer get `$_SESSION` to work."* - So, the news? Yeah, it was wrong.

Comment: Also see http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php and http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php if you just want to avoid the manual session_start() call.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry it was my friend who said it...

Comment: So, why would you want to "not" include `session_start();`, or are you just curious if you can or not? Seeing that it doesn't work without it, then I think the question's been answered ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- because PHP chucks a hissy fit if you call it more than once, which means all of the code in your project needs to collaborate somehow to make sure that doesn't happen. This means you basically have to write an entire wrapper class around session, which could be buggy and will be slower than accessing it directly. Alternatively, enable session.auto_start and you don't have to worry about any of that stuff.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert that information is for a 10 year old version of PHP and is not correct today. You can call session_start 10 times over without any issues now. `As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored`. - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky exactly. The current version of PHP will create an E_NOTICE error if you call it twice. On my servers at least, these are treated as serious.

Comment: That's Fair enough. Like the overtaking tips on your site :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible not to have `session_start()` calls on top of every page necessarily when you want to work with sessions. Thats the job of session autostart. If you set your session to auto start you can avoid those calls, otherwise you must.

> **session.auto_start boolean**
>
> session.auto_start specifies whether the session module starts a session automatically on request startup. Defaults to 0 (disabled).

So if you set `session.auto_start` to 1 in your php configuration, you wont need to start session manually.

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)**

P.S: It is working fine for your friend and not for you because he/she has enabled `session.auto_start` and you haven't touched it and by default it is disabled.